# Debug with Android Studio Using Serial Port

Tags: android, debugging, gdb, adb, remote-debugging

I usually use ADB to remotely debug with Android Studio and it work fine if the device has good Network Connection. Is there any way I can remotely debug using a serial port (which I use to get the logcat from the device ) on Baud 115200 using Ubuntu
Thank you